# Databind to dropdownlist from Sharepoint using client object model

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint, data-binding, populate

Situation:
I´m currently adding items to a sharepointlist via a .Net page and i can´t get them to display properly.
I get all the items (printer modells) from the list but displaying them in a dropdown list (modell) is not going well and the list only displays "Microsoft.Sharepoint.Client.ListItem".

Without datavaluefield and datatextvalue commented out I get errors about the fields not being found. This despite having recreated the column (to ensure that the internal name is correct) and trying both "value" and "key" in both fields with the same result.

Frankly, I´m out of ideas and googling the problem haven´t helped, even more so since most solutions refer to SPlists which is not an option.

```
using (ClientContext context = new ClientContext("[mysite]"))
        {
            context.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(username, password);
            Web site = context.Web;
            List list = site.Lists.GetByTitle("Printers");
            CamlQuery query = CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery();
            ListItemCollection collection = list.GetItems(query);
            context.Load(collection);
            context.ExecuteQuery();
            modell.DataSource = collection;
            //modell.DataValueField = "Printermodell";
            //modell.DataTextField = "Printermodell";
            modell.DataBind();
        }
```

Thankfull for any idéas / recommendations!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sample code for your reference.

```
using (ClientContext context = new ClientContext("https://domain.sharepoint.com/sites/Developer/"))
            {
                string userName = "user.onmicrosoft.com";
                string password = "pw";
                SecureString securePassword = new SecureString();
                foreach (char c in password.ToCharArray()) securePassword.AppendChar(c);
                context.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(userName, securePassword);
                Web site = context.Web;
                List list = site.Lists.GetByTitle("MyList2");
                CamlQuery query = CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery();
                Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItemCollection collection = list.GetItems(query);
                context.Load(collection);
                context.ExecuteQuery();

                foreach (Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItem item in collection)
                {
                    string text = string.Format("{0}",item.FieldValues["Title"]);
                    modell.Items.Add(new System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem(text, item.Id.ToString()));
                }
                //modell.DataSource = collection;
                //modell.DataValueField = "Printermodell";
                //modell.DataTextField = "Printermodell";
                //modell.DataBind();
            }
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Works like a charm!
Thanks a lot, really saved my sanity on this one :)